# Not able to exhibit backpressure with spring web reactive

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor, spring-webflux

I am trying to exhibit backpressure using spring-web-reactive just like the way it is shown here with akka - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oS9w3VenDW0
(Watch between 28:20 and 29:20).

To try it out I have used below sample project from github https://github.com/bclozel/spring-boot-web-reactive

Upon setup of the project I added an new endpoint in HomeController.java as shown below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/longflux",produces = "application/stream+json")
public Flux<Long> longFlux(){
    return Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(10)).log();
}
```

Now, if I try to curl this endpoint and then suspend it using (CTRL+z), backpressure should have kicked in as soon as the tcp buffers are filled and server should stop emitting the events.

However, suspending the curl command after sometime throws below exception :

```
2017-02-16 08:49:48.480 ERROR 3500 --- [        timer-1] reactor.Flux.Interval.4                  : onError(reactor.core.Exceptions$OverflowException: Could not emit value 2578 due to lack of requests)
2017-02-16 08:49:48.481 ERROR 3500 --- [        timer-1] reactor.Flux.Interval.4                  : 
reactor.core.Exceptions$OverflowException: Could not emit value 2578 due to lack of requests
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.failWithOverflow(Exceptions.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxInterval$IntervalRunnable.run(FluxInterval.java:98) ~[reactor-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SingleTimedScheduler$TimedPeriodicScheduledRunnable.run(SingleTimedScheduler.java:394) ~[reactor-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
```

I am not able to understand why the request terminated with exception in sometime after the curl command was suspended(In spring-web-reactive implementation), whereas in the akka example(as demonstrated in the youtube link) the server stopped publishing events once the tcp buffer was full.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Flux.interval` is a special case, since it's a hot source and time is not buffered by Reactor; this means that if your request cycle is slow due to backpressure and your interval source is producing faster, Reactor will emit an Error signal.

You can update this sample with a `.onBackpressureDrop()` operator to drop interval in case of backpressure. This should behave as expected.

There are many ways to illustrate backpressure, including:

- delaying the subscription with a `delay` operator
- simulating multiple slow clients (bandwidth and latency)

Comment: Thanks Brian for the pointers. I was able to illustrate back pressure now using below source code.
I didn't used the hot source this time instead created a list and then used stream to create the source.  

    @RequestMapping(value = "/longflux",produces = "application/stream+json")
    public Flux<String> longFlux(){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        for(int i=0;i<1000000;++i){
            list.add("spring-boot-starter-web-reactive");
        }
        return Flux.fromStream(list.stream()).log();
    }